# Zeromq zmsg unwrap returns empty address

Tags: c++, zeromq

Im trying to do a simple req - router example using zmsg, but it seems that when i unwrap the message, the address is invalid.

As an example: 
client.cpp

```
zmq::socket_t *client = new zmq::socket_t (context, ZMQ_REQ);
int linger = 0;
client->connect ("tcp://localhost:5555");
client->setsockopt (ZMQ_LINGER, &linger, sizeof (linger));

std::string identifier = "MDPC01";
std::string body = "Im saying hi!";
zmsg *request = new zmsg(body.c_str());
request->push_front((char *)identifier.c_str());
request->send(*client);
```

broker.cpp

```
zmq::context_t context(1);
zmq::socket_t frontend (context, ZMQ_ROUTER);
zmq::socket_t backend  (context, ZMQ_ROUTER);
frontend.bind("tcp://*:5555");    //  For clients
backend.bind("tcp://*:5556");     //  For workers

std::vector<zmq::pollitem_t> items = {{static_cast<void *> (backend), 0, ZMQ_POLLIN, 0},
{static_cast<void *> (frontend), 0, ZMQ_POLLIN, 0}};

zmq::poll (items, -1);
if (items [1].revents & ZMQ_POLLIN) {
    zmsg *client_msg = new zmsg(frontend);
    std::string address = client_msg->unwrap();
    client_msg->body_set("Replying from server!!");
    client_msg->wrap(address.c_str(),"");
    client_msg->send(frontend);
    delete client_msg;
   }
```

Thing is, if I do a msg.dump in the client before sending the message, it outputs this:

```
[006] MDPC01
[013] Im saying hi!
```

If a do the same just after receiving it on the broker, it outputs this:

```
[005] 006b8b456b
[000] 
[006] MDPC01
[00d] Im saying hi!
```

So, it has inserted at the beginning what I guess its the address. But after doing the unwrap and wrap again, if i do a dump before sending the message the output is as follows:

```
[000]  
[000] 
[006] MDPC01
[016] Replying from server!!
```

What has happened with the address? Why wasnt it inserted properly? The client now doesnt receive any messages, and my guess is that its because the router discards them for not having a proper address.

**EDIT**

Just after unwrap:

```
[006] MDPC01
[00d] Im saying hi!
```

Address just after unwrap, doing

```
std::cout << "Address -" << address << "-\n";
```

Prints:

```
Address --
```

And if I add:

```
std::cout << "Address -" << client_msg->address() << "-\n";
```

It prints:

```
Address -MDPC01-
```

Just after body_set:

```
[006] MDPC01
[016] Replying from server!!
```

Comment: Can you print `client_msg` after `unwrap()` and `body_set()` and also string `address`?

Comment: Yeah sure, but its basically the same information as the other prints.